# Laravel RESTful and multi-subdomain

Tags: laravel

there are 2 sumbdomains in my laravel app. One `api` another `storage`. I login by `api.exm.com/login` but when I want to sotre a file by `storage.exm.com/image` I get 403. How can I solve it?

Here is a section of my `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware(['api', 'return.json'])
            ->domain(subdomain(env('API_SUBDOMAIN', 'api')))
            ->namespace($this->namespace . '\Api')
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
protected function mapStorageRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware(['api', 'return.json'])
            ->domain(subdomain(env('STORAGE_SUBDOMAIN', 'storage')))
            ->namespace($this->namespace . '\Storage')
            ->group(base_path('routes/storage.php'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.  My authorize function in `StoreImageRequest` always returned `false`. :))

```
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
 public function authorize()
 {
    return false;
 }
```